# Save Excel in a Specific map in Automatically approach

Tags: spreadsheetlight

Is it possible to save a excel file in a specific folder without doing it manually?. I would like it to do it automatically.

Comment: yes, I mean folder

Comment: with C# code inside of visual studio to make it?